# Ping Linux virtual machine from Win10 host

Tags: virtualization, vmware, ping

I started the Linux virtual machine via VMWare on Win 10 host. In VMWare Network settings I chose `host-only`. After pinging the VM from the host I received answer "Request timed out".

How can I solve this, I want to use my host offline and have possibility to ping my Linux VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Wmware Network settings I chose host only.

VMware Host Only is an isolated machine.

Change your networking to NAT and Ping and Connections should work.

VMware Workstation 16.2.2 on Windows 10 Pro here with Linux and Windows Guests and pings and connection work fine.

You can use NAT or Bridged Networking for this.

..

Here is an informative article on host only guests.

[Host only guests](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Player-for-Windows/16.0/com.vmware.player.win.using.doc/GUID-93BDF7F1-D2E4-42CE-80EA-4E305337D2FC.html)

> In the default configuration, a virtual machine in a host-only network
> cannot connect to the Internet. If you install the proper routing or
> proxy software on the host system, you can establish a connection
> between the host virtual network adapter and a physical network
> adapter on the host system to connect the virtual machine to a Token
> Ring or other non-Ethernet network.
>
> On a Windows host computer, you can use host-only networking in
> combination with the Internet Connection Sharing feature in Windows to
> allow a virtual machine to use the dial-up networking adapter or other
> connection to the Internet on the host system. See Microsoft
> documentation for information on configuring Internet Connection
> Sharing.

Comment: I try NAT option but pinging is not work. My host is Win10 pro and version of VMware Workstation Player is 16.2.1

Comment: Make sure you pinged the NAT subnet (not your Host subnet).  E.g. if host is 192.168.1.x   NAT Subnet could be something like 192.168.78.x  or like .  You need to check that (check the IP of the Guest  ifconfig).

Comment: Also when you change the guest to NAT you should restart the guest.

Comment: When I use command ipconfig on my win10 host I can see 3 IPv4 adress:

1. Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1: IPv4 Adress 192.168...Subnetmask 255.255.255.0
2.Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8: IPv4 Adress 192.168...Subnetmask 255.255.255.0
3. Wireless LAN adapter WiFi: IPv4 Adress 192.168...Subnetmask 255.255.255.0

When I use command ifconfig on my Linux VM i can see
itnet 10.xxx netmask 255.255.255.0

Do I need some modification on my host network conf?

Comment: You need to show the full IP address.  192.168.....  does not help. These are internally routed IP addresses. Many many people use them. They are not exposed to the Internet.

Comment: I can see 3 IPv4 adress: 1. Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1: IPv4 Adress 192.168.145.1Subnetmask 255.255.255.0 2.Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8: IPv4 Adress 192.168.164.1 Subnetmask 255.255.255.0 3. Wireless LAN adapter WiFi: IPv4 Adress 192.168.0.102 Subnetmask 255.255.255.0

Comment: VMNet 1 is Host Only. You should be using NAT instead.  VMNet 8 is the NAT adapter.  So your Guest Linux machine has and address of 192.168.164.yyy . From your Host machine, you should be able to Ping the Linux machine. Identify yyy in the Linux machine with ifconfig.

Comment: Thank you, I set 192.168.164.1 on linux VM. Now I can ping linux VM

Comment: That's great. You can accept my answer now if all is well.